# Do I have to uinstall wamp for cakephp and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, cakephp, wamp

I used **wamp** for all my projects. But today, I was asked to use mongodb and cakephp to try something new. I have a limited knowledge on how **cakephp** works, and I was able to install **mongodb** without any problems. My dilemma are, since I am new to both technology, do I have to uninstall wamp? If yes, what is the server that I am going to use then? Still Apache? Do I have to install both Apache and PHP separately/ manually?

What do I do? Please help.

Where do I unzip the cakephp then? in the www/root folder I created for apache?

Comment: You shouldnt need to uninstall wamp, as to what to do, Google search it; SO isn't really the place for tutorials

Comment: You will need Apache to serve phpCake pages. So dont uninstall. I would suggest creating a Virtual Host for your new app to live in. Give this a coat of looking at for how to setup a vhost `http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113228,113234#msg-113234`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP is just a framework that runs on top of Apache+PHP and MongoDB is just a database like MySQL (which comes with WAMP). As MySQL and MongoDB don't conflict at all, you shouldn't uninstall anything. You will still need the A (apache) and P (PHP) of your WAMP stack.